# Как обнулить временную составляющую значения колонки с датой?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Имеется колонка с датами формата: `2006-07-21 11:41:06.179131`, которые нужно привести к следующему формату: `2006-07-21 00:00:00.000000`

Пробовал сделать так:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x:x.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=1))
```

Возвращается дата в таком формате: `2006-07-21 00:00:00.000001`, если `microsecond=0`, тогда вообще пропадает весь хвост после `2006-07-21`.

Comment: это же просто формат отображения. разве нет?

Answer (score 2):

"Хвост" не пропадает - просто Pandas не показывает компонент времени если у **всех** дат в столбце время нулевое (`00:00:00.000000`).

Пример:

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({"DT":["2006-07-21 11:41:06.179131", "2006-07-21 12:00:00.123456"], "VAL":[11,12]})

In [46]: df["DT"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DT"])

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
                          DT  VAL
0 2006-07-21 11:41:06.179131   11
1 2006-07-21 12:00:00.123456   12

In [48]: df.dtypes
Out[48]:
DT     datetime64[ns]
VAL             int64
dtype: object

In [49]: df["DT"] = df["DT"].dt.floor("D")

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
          DT  VAL
0 2006-07-21   11
1 2006-07-21   12

In [51]: df.to_dict()
Out[51]:
{'DT': {0: Timestamp('2006-07-21 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2006-07-21 00:00:00')},
 'VAL': {0: 11, 1: 12}}

In [52]: df.dtypes
Out[52]:
DT     datetime64[ns]
VAL             int64
dtype: object
```

а теперь прибавим  одну миллисекунду в последней строке:

```
In [54]: df.loc[1, "DT"] += pd.offsets.Milli(1)

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
                       DT  VAL
0 2006-07-21 00:00:00.000   11
1 2006-07-21 00:00:00.001   12
```